# Can't log in a user in MVC!

Tags: asp.net-mvc, forms-authentication

I have been scratching my head on this for a while now but still can't get it.
I'm trying to simply log in a user in an MVC2 application.

I have tried everything that I know to try but still can't figure out what I'm doing wrong.
Here are a few things that I have tried:

```
FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie( emailAddress, rememberMe );  
var cookie = FormsAuthentication.GetAuthCookie( emailAddress, rememberMe );  
HttpContext.Response.Cookies.Add( cookie );  
FormsAuthenticationTicket ticket = new FormsAuthenticationTicket( emailAddress, rememberMe, 15 );  
FormsIdentity identity = new FormsIdentity( ticket );  
GenericPrincipal principal = new GenericPrincipal(identity, new string[0]);  
HttpContext.User = principal;
```

I'm not sure if any of this is the right thing to do (as it's not working).
After setting `HttpContext.User = principal` then `Request.IsAuthenticated == true`.
However, in Global.asax I have this:

```
HttpCookie authenCookie = Context.Request.Cookies.Get( 
    FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName );
```

The only cookie that ever is available is the aspnet session cookie.

Any ideas at all would be much appreciated!

Comment: Are you saying that a new default ASP.NET MVC 2 project doesn't work? If not, have you tried using a default project to see if that works?

Comment: The default mvc2 project does work.  I have no idea of how I may have screwed that up!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're doing way too much work. It takes one function call to log someone in. Here's the boilerplate code from a new MVC 2 app:

```
    private bool ValidateLogOn(string userName, string password)
    {
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(userName))
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError("username", "You must specify a username.");
        }
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(password))
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError("password", "You must specify a password.");
        }
        if (!MembershipService.ValidateUser(userName, password)) // this is the login
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError("_FORM", "The username or password provided is incorrect.");
        }

        return ModelState.IsValid;
    }
```

Note the commented line. That's all you need to do a login. I note that you're not calling `ValidateUser` in your code in the question. You need that.

Comment: ValidateLogOn isn't my issue.

The only reason I have all of that stuff is because it wasn't working.

Comment: Ok so I have removed everything other than 

FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie( emailAddress, rememberMe );

and it still doesn't work.  ValidateLogOn doesn't perform the actual login.  It only validates that the credentials exist in the datastore.

Any other thoughts?

Comment: Read the rest of `AccountController.cs` in a default MVC project. The `LogOn` action first calls `ValidateLogOn`, Then `FormsAuth.SignIn`.

Comment: Right but ValidateLogOn only makes sure that the credentials exist. That shouldn't have anything to do with the forms auth functionality other then for error messages. Am I wrong in that statement?

Comment: I think I may know the answer.  Do you have to use a membership provider to use FormsAuthentication?  If so, I definitely was not aware of this and definitely am not using a Membership provider.  That is why I was so confused about why ValidateLogOn was so important.

Comment: Yes, you need a membership provider.